# How to select checkbox and radio buttons automatically using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, checkbox, radio-button

I have checkbox and a radio button. The scenario is when the user selects a country from select menu, i want to select the checkbox and radio button automatically. Is this possible with angularjs html tags? please help

**View**

```
<select name="country_0" ng-model="item.country" ng-options="" required="required" class="ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" style=""><option value="" selected="selected"></option><option label="AFGHANISTAN" value="object:835">AFGHANISTAN</option><option label="cayman islands" value="object:836">cayman islands</option><option label="ALBANIA" value="object:837">ALBANIA</option><option label="ALGERIA" value="object:838">ALGERIA</option><option label="AMERICAN SAMOA" value="object:839">AMERICAN SAMOA</option></select>
<div class="row">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.noTin" ng-disabled="item.tin" ng-checked="showReasonA(true)" ng-required="item.noTin" name="checkboxNoTin"/>
  </label><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.yes.me_no_tin" style="margin-top: 10px" class="col-value"></span>
</div>
<div ng-if="item.noTin" class="row">
  <div class="col padding-top-xs"><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.select_reason" style="margin-bottom: 12px;" class="pol-value col-value"></span>
    <div ng-if="item.country.tin == true" ng-init="item.reason = 0" class="row margin-bottom-medium">
      <label class="radio-button">
        <input type="radio" name="reason" ng-model="item.reason" ng-value="A" required="required"/><span class="indicator"></span><span>REASON A</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!showReasonA(false)" class="row margin-bottom-medium">
      <div class="col">
        <label class="radio-button">
          <input type="radio" name="reason" ng-model="item.reason" ng-value="B" required="required"/><span class="indicator"></span><span>REASON B</span>
          <label class="item item-input input-margin">
            <textarea ng-model="item.othersReason" ng-required="item.reason == 2" rows="5"></textarea>
          </label>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!showReasonA(false)" class="row margin-bottom-medium">
      <div class="col">
        <label class="radio-button">
          <input type="radio" name="reason" ng-model="item.reason" ng-value="C" required="required"/><span class="indicator"></span><span>REASON C</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
$scope.showReasonA = function showReasonA(checkNoTin) {
    console.log("print the notin value from data",this.item.noTin);
    if (!this.item.country) return false;
    var selectedCountry;
    var fourCountries = ["cayman islands", "ALBANIA"]
    var isIt = fourCountries.indexOf(selectedCountry) >= 0;
    console.log("print match country val",isIt);
    console.log("get checknotin value before assign",checkNoTin);
    if (checkNoTin) this.item.noTin = true;
    console.log("final checknotin val",checkNoTin);
    return isIt;
  }
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lini7/knfsv64m/11

Comment: What you tried? Can you share your code here?

Comment: It is possible, but you should try it yourself first. If you have problem with your code you can share the code, it is easier to help you from there.

Comment: @samAlvin without trying i wont post the question here.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with angularjs.

Comment: @digit how its possible.describe

Comment: which checkbox and which radio button should be selected?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- the first checkbox and the reason A should get selected